# What is the best way to indicate an element is resizeable by dragging at the bottom right corner?

Tags: website-design, wysiwyg

I am building a kind of "what you see is what you get" web editor, I have a couple of widgets, buttons, slideshows, images, which are resizeable by dragging the bottom right corner only, like an html textarea. But the "double bottom right arrow" in a textarea does not look good on my widgets as they are very dynamic, sizes and colors can be changed as often as the user wants.

What is the best way to indicate & style the resize handle? Is there an example site I can look at?

Any pointer is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can find [examples](http://codeidol.com/java/swing/Windows,-Dialogs,-and-Frames/Add-Windows-Resize-Icons/) online; still bear in mind that familiarity is important. [User expectations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_expectations) are really important in UX, so much that you might want to stick with some visually suboptimal components rather than violate **consistency**.

After all, you want your widgets to be used by many, not just look good but be underused.